ADFS SAML token digest validation failing
My issue is similar to the question in this post How is an ADFS SAML token's digest value calculated? However the answer mentioned there did not help me. Hence asking again. I am trying to validate the signature of a signed SAML assertion from ADFS. So first I am trying to compute the hash of the assertion block after removing the entire signature node using sha256. Prior to computing the hash, I am canonicalizing the assertion block using exclusive cn14. The assertion block before applying canonicalization is as below
  <Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_adbc1f5f-2727-46f4-aa0b-9b91b14dfc3c" IssueInstant="2024-08-06T23:26:19.084Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer>http://test-adfs.countryeast.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><Subject><NameID>test.test_user@test-adfs.local</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-08-06T23:31:19.084Z" Recipient="https://192.168.0.1/login"/></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Conditions NotBefore="2024-08-06T23:26:19.079Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-08-07T00:26:19.079Z"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>https://192.168.0.1/adfs/services/trust</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"><AttributeValue>test_user</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>admin</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2024-08-06T23:26:19.009Z" SessionIndex="_adbc1f5f-2727-46f4-aa0b-9b91b14dfc3c"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion>  

The canonicalized assertion block is as follows
<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_adbc1f5f-2727-46f4-aa0b-9b91b14dfc3c" IssueInstant="2024-08-06T23:26:19.084Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer>http://test-adfs.countryeast.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><Subject><NameID>test.test_user@test-adfs.local</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-08-06T23:31:19.084Z" Recipient="https://192.168.0.1/login"></SubjectConfirmationData></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Conditions NotBefore="2024-08-06T23:26:19.079Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-08-07T00:26:19.079Z"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>https://192.168.0.1/adfs/services/trust</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"><AttributeValue>test_user</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>admin</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2024-08-06T23:26:19.009Z" SessionIndex="_adbc1f5f-2727-46f4-aa0b-9b91b14dfc3c"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion>

I am computing the hash as below
echo -n "<Assertion xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="_adbc1f5f-2727-46f4-aa0b-9b91b14dfc3c" IssueInstant="2024-08-06T23:26:19.084Z" Version="2.0"><Issuer>http://test-adfs.countryeast.cloudapp.azure.com/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><Subject><NameID>test.test_user@test-adfs.local</NameID><SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2024-08-06T23:31:19.084Z" Recipient="https://192.168.0.1/login"/></SubjectConfirmation></Subject><Conditions NotBefore="2024-08-06T23:26:19.079Z" NotOnOrAfter="2024-08-07T00:26:19.079Z"><AudienceRestriction><Audience>https://192.168.0.1/adfs/services/trust</Audience></AudienceRestriction></Conditions><AttributeStatement><Attribute Name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"><AttributeValue>test_user</AttributeValue><AttributeValue>admin</AttributeValue></Attribute></AttributeStatement><AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2024-08-06T23:26:19.009Z" SessionIndex="_adbc1f5f-2727-46f4-aa0b-9b91b14dfc3c"><AuthnContext><AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef></AuthnContext></AuthnStatement></Assertion>" | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64 

I am expecting the output of the above command to match the DigestValue encoded in the SAML response but they do not match.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

So what's the "DigestValue encoded in the SAML response"? You didn't post that, so we can't even get started with debugging for you (if debugging this is on-topic for Crypto.SE).

@DannyNiu thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I am unable to provide the full saml response xml here. However, I got this working by removing the last trailing newline from the canonicalized xml using xmllint --exc-c14n -. Package detail: https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint

I added a link to xmllint. If that's not the version you're using, please edit
